# Two way binding with converter without source modification

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, converters

I want to use linq grouping as itemssource for checkbox listview

It my data model:

```
public class GroupItem
{
   public string name GroupName { get; set; }
   public string boolean GroupItemFlag { get; set; }
}
```

It view model (data context):

```
...
IEnumerable<GroupItem> _groupItems;

public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,GroupItem>> Groups
{
   get { return _groupItems.GroupBy(__item=>__item.GroupName); }
}
...
```

it view:

```
...
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Groups}>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource groupingToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </StackPanel>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
...
```

groupingToBooleanConverter code:

```
public class GroupingToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var group = value as IGrouping<string,GroupItem>;
        return group.Any(__item => __item.GroupItemFlag);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // problem here
        // how to set for all group items GroupItemFlag=(bool)value;
    }
}
```

I don't want create one more class "Group" for this, so i use IGrouping and converter.

May be I chose the wrong way?

Comment: Hi Denis,Its seems to be good as you need group items and handle there keys for there group name.

Comment: Actually this is an opinion based question. 
I will tell my opinion anyway. It’s quite appreciable to do the way you’re following now. Normally this is the way to do things in MVVM. You separate the Model, ViewModel logic and view. Any conversions from ViewModel to View could be achieved easily with Converters.

But I am doubtful about the last sentence. Why do you want to create one more class ‘Group’?

Comment: I want to get checkbox listview of group names. Checkbox is checked if any one element of group is checked. And if Checkbox changed, Checkbox value will be set for all group items

Comment: @ViVi: responsibility of viewmodel should be to expose data and logic from model in such way that is easily consumable from view. If you have to write a lot of converters, then it is not such easily consumable :) `GroupingToBooleanConverter.ConvertBack` method smells with application logic. Ideally you should put only UI logic into converters, BooleanToVisibilityConverter as greatest example. I could accept also some kind of EnumToColor converter.

Comment: It's only simple example. Question not about responsibility of viewmodel. GroupItem may be is view element. I want manipulate all group items by single check box.

Comment: @Liero: Even I did not mean that we should write lot of converters. If it is manageable with a converter it should be used. Like if I have a list of strings or int values that are to be bound to checkbox checked state, I could create a converter. Agree with your point anyway.

Comment: @DenisFedak: If you want universal solution, create custom control (without mvvm). Also, check collectionview grouping feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it even without converter:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=GroupItemFlag, Mode=OneWay}"
          Command="{Binding DataContext.ToogleGroupCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

```
void ToogleGroupCommand_Execute(IGrouping<string, GroupItem> group){
    bool newValue = !group.First().GroupItemFlag;
    foreach(var item in group) item.GroupItemFlag = newValue; 
}
```

if you are not using MVVM, then just handle Checked and Unchecked events.

However, if you are using MVVM, I highly recommend you to create Group class as ViVi suggests:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
   Groups = _groupItems.GroupBy(i => i.GroupName).Select(i => new GroupViewModel(i.Key, i);
}
public Groups[] Groups {get;}


public class GroupViewModel
{
    public GroupViewModel(string name, IEnumerable<GroupItem> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupItem> Items { get; }


    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            if (Items.All(i => i.GroupItemFlag)) return true;
            if (Items.Any(i => i.GroupItemFlag)) return null;
            return false;
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                item.GroupItemFlag = value.GetValueOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Liero, it is a sure way. I assumed them. But I think, exist best practice.

Comment: many times, event handlers in codebehind will make your life much more easier. You dont need to write application logic in codebehind, you can call viewmodel methods from codebehind. It is not violation of mvvm. if it helps you, just use it.